# MIMO control: static inverse plant decoupling

Tags: mechanical-engineering, control-engineering, frequency-response

I am using techniques explained in the book of Skogestag, Multivariable feedback control, for feedback control of a MIMO plant. In this book they explain the phenomena of static inverse plant decoupling in which the interaction of the off-diagonal terms are eliminated.

I have a triangular MIMO plant in which one of the off-diagonal components is zero. Is it still usefull to apply static inverse plant decoupling in this case?

Comment: Does the required inverse still exist? If yes, you should still be able to statically decouple the plant. Seems useful to me ...

Answer (score 1):

If a MIMO plant is upper or lower triangular then one can't create an interaction loop which might make the system unstable. So using stabilizing SISO feedback control for each diagonal term should stabilize the system. Therefore from a stability standpoint decoupling would not be necessary.

That being said, if reference is not the equilibrium point then some of the outputs will also be affected by the other references as well. So complete decoupling might improve the tracking performance. But feed forward could be used for this as well.